# How do I format a number?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, formatting, qstring

How do I format a number the following way?

input:

```
123
```

output:

```
1.2-3
```

In C#, there's a `ToString()` overload for integer types that does the job:

```
123.ToString(@"0\.0-0"); //output 1.2-3
```

Is there something like this in Qt? I did read [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstring.html) documentation but couldn't manage to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, you could do:

```
int number = 123;
QString s = QString("%1.%2-%3").arg(
    QString::number((number / 100) % 10),
    QString::number((number / 10) % 10),
    QString::number(number % 10));
```

or:

```
QString s = QString::number(123);
s.insert(1, QChar('.'));
s.insert(3, QChar('-'));
```

Comment: The second approach seems better in my case since the number is a bit larger than the one in my example 

e: but this result in a lot of reallocations..

Comment: I thought you only needed to do it for three-digit numbers. You might also want to check, whether the number is negative if that's a possibility.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in function for formatting an integer to string, but you can perform your custom formatting by your own custom function to do so.